# Разработка Discord-ботов на discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Я пишу функцию, которая изменяет название канала когда кто-либо покидает или приходит на сервер.
Она выводит количество участников сервера. Но иногда она лагает и не реагирует на то, что кто-то пришел или ушел с сервера.
Вот код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member:discord.Member):
    CountChannel = bot.get_channel(727401938001461298)

    await CountChannel.edit(
            name = "Участников: {}".format(len(member.guild.members))
        )

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member:discord.Member):
    CountChannel = bot.get_channel(727401938001461298)

    await CountChannel.edit(
            name = "Участников: {}".format(len(member.guild.members))
        )
```

В чем проблема? Может, так происходит потому что у меня комп тормозит?

Answer (score 2):

Discord с недавних пор имеет ограничение на 2 редактирования названия/описания канала в 10 минут:
[image: The new rate limit for channel NAME AND TOPIC updates is 2 updates per 10 minutes, per channel.]

После двух редактирований срабатывает "ratelimit" и библиотека задерживает изменение канала до окончания задержки.

Возможные решения:

- Отказаться от каналов со статистикой
- Добавить проверку на время прошедшее с момента последнего изменения канала
- Изменять канал каждые 5 минут, например при помощи `discord.ext.tasks`:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

...

update_required = False

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member:discord.Member):
    update_required = True

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member:discord.Member):
    update_required = True

@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def stats_update():
    if update_required:
        count_channel = bot.get_channel(727401938001461298) # CamelCase обычно обозначают Classы: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions
        await count_channel.edit(name = f"Участников: {len(channel.guild.members)}")
        update_required = False

stats_update.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто сделайте цикл, в котором бот будет удалять канал и менять его название на текущее количество участников, когда кто-то присоединяется к серверу:

```
@client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        overwrites={
            member.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False),
            member.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False)}
        category = await member.guild.create_category('Инфо')
        await member.guild.create_voice_channel('Участников:'
            .format(member.guild.member_count), overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
        await channel.delete()
        # И так по кругу
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]