# Разработка Discord-ботов на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Как сделать функцию, которая изменяет название канала когда кто-то покидает или приходит на сервер. Она выводит количество участников сервера?
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1147354/394322

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разработка Discord-ботов на discord.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147354/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-discord-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйte команду:

```
await ctx.channel.edit(name = f'Участники {member.count}')
```